# Insulated Wire - Radio Signal

Tags: electrical-engineering, electromagnetism

I am looking for a relativity inexpensive wire for consumers whose insulating jacket will prevent radio signals from leaking.

We are installing a pet radio fence at home. If you are unfamiliar with this system, you place a wire around a perimeter and a collar on the dog. A transmitter sends a signal around the wire and the collar picks up this signal giving the dog a warning/shock to keep them inside.

In our case, we want to double the wire back on itself but, because the wires are so close, this causes, what I can only assume is, deconstructive interference and cancels the signal out. To solve this, I want to run the normal "transmitting" wire in one direction and then an insulated wire in the opposite direction that contains the signal. Do you know what type of wire jacket can do this?

I'm not an engineer, so if anything here sounds off, it's because it is. Thanks.

Comment: Shielding doesn't work like that. I think that long wire isn't actually operating as an antenna either but as some sort of inductive pickup.

Comment: From manufacture website: "A radio signal travels from the Fence Transmitter through a buried wire....". Looks like most of these products use either a AM or FM signal. When you say "shielding doesn't work like that" are saying you can't shield the AM signal? I was hoping a coax cable might do this?

Comment: I'm just saying that there's a lot more to shielding than just putting metal between you and thing. Signals travel along the surface of shields from the outside to the inside and capacitively couple to everything. Basically, there is more to shielding than just surrounding something with metal or putting metal between two things. Coax cable can shield, but there's reason they have 360 degree enclosed metal connectors on both ends which then screw into another connector that is 360 degree enclosed which itself is mounted on a metal enclosure that is also 360 degree enclosed.

Comment: And in your case, i doubt destructive interference is going to happen because the signal is at different states along the cable. It's not like you're sending two opposite but symmetrical signals down two cables from one end. You're sending something up then back. It's like assuming that you'll make no sound when you yell just because there is an echo in the room.

Comment: The first sentence made me think the jacket was something the consumer was wearing. :)

Comment: What's the geometry of your layout? I can't imagine a setup that's not a loop enclosing the space you want to keep your dog in.

Comment: It's a C shape with the open portion of the C facing the house. He needs to be able to go up to the house.

Comment: C shape is what I'd expect. Are you running the wire out and then back in the same trench because the wire in the kit is too long for your yard? The instructions should tell you how to terminate the wire for a short loop.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do it? I own a similar system and run the wire alongside the outer wall of the house. The collars also trigger indoors near that wall, and I would like to shield that section.

Comment: No, I didn't get the wired solution working. I tried using some spare coax cabling I had but it had no effect, the signal wasn't damped at all. Probably as DKNguyen said, shielding doesn't work the way I had expected. We switched to using a wireless radio fence and that has worked really well.